# What exactly is Kernel in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

**What exactly is Kernel in jupyter notebook?**

I know that the task of the kernel is to run programs, but this definition overlaps with the task of some other concepts in programming languages, and I don't understand the difference between them!

Comment: See [here](https://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/what_is_jupyter.html#kernel) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52370092/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47554722/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68460264/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71040470/8508004). Then update your question and title to address what specifically isn't covered elsewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a kernel in Jupyter Notebook and how it is different/similar to actual kernel (related to Operating System)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370092/what-is-a-kernel-in-jupyter-notebook-and-how-it-is-different-similar-to-actual-k)